# Perform an action on an entity after a fixed time

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, event-handling

In my Spring project, I have an entity `Customer`.
Now once we get a new Customer, we persist it in our system, and exactly after one hour, I want to check if the `Customer` has made any purchase.
If yes, I take some action. If no, the some other.

I contemplated two strategies, 
1) Firing up an event when the Customer is persisted. And then having the event listener thread sleep for one hour. I believe this will be a very bad way to handle this.

2) Having a cron check every once in a while for customers for whom one hour has passed since registration. But then, I figure it will be very difficult to be accurate. I would have to run the cron every minute which won't be great.

Any ideas?

Comment: *But then, I figure it will be very difficult to be accurate* - why do you think that?

Comment: *I would have to run the cron every minute which won't be great.* - again why?

Comment: @ScaryWombat : is it good to have some process run so frequently?

Comment: There are many ways to schedule a single execution task after a set amount of time, depending on your technology stack. You could even opt for something as simple as Timer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-

Comment: Every Minute is not so frequent, 1000 per second more so.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thanks for this. got me searching for right things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the '[ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)' which as per javadoc is:

> A ThreadPoolExecutor that can additionally schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically

In your case, when a customer is created, you can use the 'schedule' method to wake up after 1 hour and then perform required activities. This method can also be used if you want those activities to be executed periodically as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)
But this guided me towards right things.

Answer (score 0):

I believe run the cron every minute is not that bad, how many customers would you handle in one minute?

Answer (score 0):

Although not sure why you cannot use the event when a registered Customer will make any purchase i.e. when a particular registered customer will make purchase you can take the action inline as and then.

You described 2 strategies both will work but I would prefer to run cron job which you can configure explicitly. In that way you avoid the overhead of maintaining the threads. If you configure the cron job timing correctly and allow a single job to run at a time I do not see any problem with that. Remember cron jobs are used for batch processing rather than handling events.